# XPath Elements lower than a certain number

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to apply a XPath to my XML, in order to find the items that cost less than 1.00 from a certain category.

Here is a sample of my XML:

```
<Shop>
  <Category name="Fish">
    <Article id="1" nome="Tuna">
        <Price>0.90</Price>
        <stock>100</stock>
    </Article>
    <Article id="2" name="Sword Fish">
        <Price>1.50</Price>
        <stock>100</stock>
    </Article>
  </Category>   
</Shop>
```

And I have this XPath:

```
Shop/Category[name="Fish"]/Article[Price<=1.00]
```

I want to find all price that cost less than 1.00 from the category Fish.. The error here exists in *`Category[name="Fish"]`* (and I need to apply that filter) cause if I execute this XPath:

```
Shop/Category/Article[Price<=1.00]
```

The correct list of nodes is returned successfully.

Comment: Use `@name` to access attributes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use an `@` when targetting the name attribute:

```
Shop/Category[@name="Fish"]/Article[Price<=1.00]
```

Comment: Can't we simply delete simple 1 character typo questions like this?

Comment: @ThomasWeller of course we can. *Edit:* they can be closed, but I doubt they'll be deleted.